# Matlab saving figure with file name containing variables

Tags: matlab, variables, save, figure

I have no idea how to save file when the name contains variables.

```
A = figure();

% some code

fileName = sprintf('sig1=%d mu1 =%d p1=%.2f sig2 = %d mu2 = %d p2 = %.2f', ...
                     sigma1, mi1, double(p1), sigma2, mi2, double(p2));

print(A, fileName, '-dpng');
```

Comment: So are you asking how to take a variable name from the workspace and save your figure based on this name?  I don't understand your question.

Comment: I didn't know how to percise the question :< But you are right. I need to save my figure with the name base on it's variables.

Comment: You can use `whos` to get a cell array of variable names, then use those and integrate it into your output string.

Comment: @vizhanyolajos - Your proposed edits were flawed.  If you want to continue to the next line, you need a triple pair of dots (`...`) to signify that the command is continuing.  Not doing this will be interpreted as the end of the command and you will get a syntax error.  I've approved the edit in any case as block formatting the code is proper, but be mindful when proposing edits that don't work.

Comment: I don't know what OS you're using, but that doesn't look like a valid file name to me. What string are you trying to get out of your `sprintf`?

Comment: @beaker - Yup.  The equals signs alone make it invalid.

Comment: I'm using sprintf. When I display the string I see exactly what I wanted to get. The problem comes when I use it as a name of my file.

"Error using name (line 103)
Cannot create output file '.\sig1=3 mu1 =3 p1=0.30 sig2 = 5 mu2 = 7 p2 = 0.70'"

Comment: @Matt That's not a valid file name in any OS I'm familiar with.

Comment: Have you heard of Windows 7? Ok, i will save about 100 figures manually. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Matt Well, imagine that. According to [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/272172) you might need to reference the cell contents like so: `fileName{1}`. Good luck.

Comment: @rayryeng TIL that `=` is a valid character in NTFS file names. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#naming_conventions

Comment: @beaker huh! What do you know lol. I never needed to use equals anyway. Seems odd here.

Comment: @beaker, that's a perfectly fine (if weird) filename on Linux. And if = is a valid filename character on Windows, I don't see why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Maybe Windows (or Matlab on Windows) enforces a filename to have an extension? Though I guess '.70' would fulfill that role. Adding a '.png' as in Brian's answer is a good idea though anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work:

```
A = figure;
plot(1:10,sin(pi*(1:10)./4))

fileName = sprintf('sig1=%d mu1 =%d p1=%.2f sig2 = %d mu2 = %d p2 = %.2f.png', ...
                     1, 2, double(3), 4, 5, double(6));

print(A, fileName, '-dpng');
```

The png file opened just fine. When you want the png file name to have variables in it, this is the correct approach. You can set a lot more figure specifications by using the figure handle ("A", in this case) and the `set(A,...)` function. Look at the matlab documentation for using the `set(A,...)` function and `gcf`. If you type `get(A)`, you will see a list of properties that you can set before you save your figure.

Please let me know if this helps.